# Why is $E$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have some queries about this proof (towards the last part of this text).

1) Firstly, why is $E=\{x\in X:g(x)<\infty\}$ measurable?

2) Secondly, why is $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$? Is it because $\|g\|_p$ is bounded, so that that the set on which $g$ is infinite must be of measure zero?

3) Finally, why does it follow that the series in (6.9) converges and $g\chi_E$ is in $L_p$?

Thanks for any help.
[image]

Comment: Is this from Bartle ?

Comment: @halvet Yes, it is from Bartle's Elements of Integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give reasons briefly. If you have question, please give me a comment.

(1) Note that for each $n$,
$$\{ g(x)<n\}$$ is measurable since $g$ is measurable. Countable union of measurable set is measurable.

(2) Use Chebyshev's inequality.

(3) Split the integral. Integral over Measure zero set is zero.

Comment: Thanks, this is very enlightening!

Comment: Just one more question: Why the series in (6.9) converges almost everywhere?

Comment: @yoyostein what is the definition of a.e.? Recall that we proved $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$.

Comment: Hmm.. Why does the series converge in the first place? Is it because of monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @yoyostein yes that is right.